# hwo to make MATERIALIZED view for join query with trigger function?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

4 tables exist with structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqPe4.png)

```
CREATE TABLE public.type
(
  id serial,
  name text,
  groups_id integer,
  comment text
)
CREATE TABLE public.berand
(
  id serial,
  name text,
  type_id integer,
  comment text
)
CREATE TABLE public.model
(
  id serial,
  name text,
  berand_id integer,
  comment text
)
CREATE TABLE public.versions
(
  id serial,
  name text,
  model_id integer,
  comment text
)
```

this is slow query

```
SELECT id,name tname, bname, mname, vname 
FROM type 
left join(
  select  berand.type_id, berand.name bname,mname,vname 
  from berand 
    left join (
     select   model.name mname, versions.name vname,model.berand_id 
     from model 
      left join  versions on versions.model_id = model.id
    ) m on berand.id = m.berand_id
) b on  b.type_id = type.id
```

bellow is function and trigger for refresh MATERIALIZED view with chnage table

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW v_tbmv
AS 
SELECT id,name tname, bname, mname, vname FROM type left join(select  berand.type_id, berand.name bname,mname,vname from berand left join (select   model.name mname, versions.name vname,model.berand_id from model left join  versions on versions.model_id = model.id) m on berand.id = m.berand_id) b on  b.type_id = type.id

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_refresh_v_tbmv()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW v_tbmv;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_refresh_v_tbmv_type AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON type
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_refresh_v_tbmv();

CREATE TRIGGER tg_refresh_v_tbmv_berand AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON berand
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_refresh_v_tbmv();

CREATE TRIGGER tg_refresh_v_tbmv_model AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON model
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_refresh_v_tbmv();

CREATE TRIGGER tg_refresh_v_tbmv_versions AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON type
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_refresh_v_tbmv();
```

Comment: What is your question? Refreshing a slow materialized view on every data modification is not the smartest of ideas.

Comment: It will not matter for performance, but you can simplify your statement. Those nested derived tables are not needed. So you can simply write `from type left join berand on ... left join model on ... left join versions on ...`